# php multi array

Tags: arrays

What if I have a multidimensional array, in which I want to make combinations. So for example if I have 3 arrays:

- Array(1,2)
- Array(7,3)
- Array(3,9,8,2)

Then I want a function which make combinations like: array( array(1,7) array(1,3) array( 3,9) etcetera but also array(7,3) array(7,9)

Plus it must check the availability so if the numbers are not available then do not make combinations with them.

Now I got this, and further I cant get:

```
   $xCombinations =
            Array(
                Array(1,2)
                Array(7,3)
                Array(3,9,8,2)
            );



            $available = Array([1] => 2,[2] => 1, [7]=>3,[3]=>4, [8]=>2, [2]=>4);

            $combination = Array();

            recursiveArray($xCombinations);

            function recursiveArray($tmpArr){
               if($tmpArr){
                 foreach ($tmpArr)as $value) {
                   if (is_array($value)) {
                      displayArrayRecursively($value);
                   } else {
                    //here 1st time $value would be 1, 
                    //so this must now be combined with 7 , 3 , 9, 8 ,2 > 
                    //so you will get an array of array(1,7) array, (1,3) array (3,9) 
                    //etcetera.. there arrays must be also in a multidimensional array
                   }
                 }
               }
            }
```

Comment: If you have three arrays, wouldn't it be more natural to have an output size of three elements for each result?

Comment: Is this just a hypothetical quiz question? Or is there a practical use to this? As it stands, I have little clue on what you are trying to accomplish.. Can you give a practical example ?

Comment: ok i will type the example at the end of the question now, just a moment

Comment: what does that mean "availability" for `3` is `2`? So maximum two occurrences of `3` per tuple? or per whole set? or what?

Comment: actually no. Its actually for this.. if the first array has for example 2 arrays: array(1,2) and array(1,3) then the combinations must be 1+1 , 1+3, 2+1, 2+3.. But if the availability of 1 is only 1 then you can't have 1+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue consists ow two parts. Actually, it can be implemented with one functional block, but that would be hard to read. So, I'll split it to two operations.

**Retrieving combinations**

First task is to get all combinations. By definition, those combinations are [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of your array members. That could be produced without recursion, like:

```
$result = array_reduce(array_slice($input, 1), function($c, $x)
{
   return call_user_func_array('array_merge', 
      array_map(function($y) use ($c)
      {
         return array_map(function($z) use ($y)
         {
            return array_merge((array)$z, (array)$y);
         }, $c);
      }, $x)
   );
}, current($input));
```

Here we're accumulating our tuples one be one. Result is just all possible combinations as it should be for Cartesian product.

**Filtering result**

This is another part of the issue. Assuming you have `$available` as a set of `key=>value` pairs, where `key` corresponds to specific number in a tuple and `value` corresponds to how many times can that number appear in that tuple at most, here's simple filtering code:

```
$result = array_filter($result, function($tuple) use ($available)
{
   foreach(array_count_values($tuple) as $value=>$count)
   {
      if(isset($available[$value]) && $available[$value]<$count)
      {
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
});
```

For instance, if we have `$input` as

```
$input = [
   [1,3],
   [1,6]
];
```

and restrictions on it as

```
$available = [6=>0, 1=>1];
```

Then result would be only

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(3)
    [1]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

since only this tuple fulfills all requirements (so it has not `6` and `1` appeared once in it)

Comment: very good explanation. But if available is for example available [1]=>1 and you have array for example like arra(1,2) array(1,3,4,5) array(7,5,6) then there must be these combinations: 1+3, 1+4, 1+5, 1+4, 1+5, 1+6 1+7,  and here no 1+1 because there is 1 availability for 1

Comment: That's exactly what will happen. So if some combination will have `1` more than once, it will be excluded

Comment: Could you please explain this, because i don't really get what you have done. I try to figure out but very hard tbh

Comment: Well, first of - does it work as it's required? If yes, then, I guess, explanation is inside the answer (so we're producing all combinations, then we're filtering them)

Comment: Echo? It's an array, so I'm not using "echo" It's `var_dump()` output

Comment: Alma Do, I discovered a flaw.
What it's not dynamic, what if you have $input = [
   [1,3],
   [1,6], [7,8]
]; then this code won't work

Comment: alma do, could you please explain this one:  array_map(function($y) use ($c)  how you use function($y) why y?

Comment: Why `use($y)`? Well, because closures in PHP can not access context without specifying needed variables from that context inside `use(..)` block

Comment: also in beginning for function(c,x) how does this works if array input has like 5 arrays??

Comment: It works because `array_reduce()` will proceed elements one-by-one, storing current result in `$c`. You can refer to [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/array_reduce) for more details

Comment: so actually $y will be a temp variable for $c without changing anything for C?

Comment: what if you have array like $input = [ [1,3], [1,6], [7,8] ];  in first instance what will $c be and what will $x is it like first time $c[1,3] x $x=[1,6] second time $c[1,6] x $y[7,8]

Comment: With sample above, first time it will be Cartesian product of `[1,3]` and `[1,6]`, second time it will be Cartesian product of what we've got on previous step and `[7,8]`