# How can I replace two foreach loops to one assignment (mb two array_map functions)?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays and I want to get the result array where each element is kind of cartesian product of these 2 arrays.
With `foreach`'s it looks like this:

```php
$first = [1, 2, 3];
$second = ["A", "B"];
$res = [];
foreach($first as $num)
  foreach($second as $sym)
    $res[] = "$num $sym"; // the same as $num . " " . $sym

// Now res is ["1 A", "1 B", "2 A", "2 B", "3 A", "3 B"]
```

How can I get the same result array with `array_map`? Something like:

```php
$res = array_map(
  fn($num) => array_map(
    fn($sym) => "$num $sym",
    $second
  ),
  $first
);

// Of course it's wrong
// Here res will be [["1 A", "1 B"], ["2 A", "2 B"], ["3 A", "3 B"]]
```

Mb there are other functions besides `array_map`. The main thing is `$res = ...`, means that `$res` should be assign to something that returns a result array.
Thanks.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/eiUlm

Comment: Why has a veteran contributor posted an unexplained answer as a comment?  Should it be deleted?

Comment: [Related question with lackluster title](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24524816/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want response like this `["1 A", "1 B", "2 A", "2 B", "3 A", "3 B"]` and use `array_map` you can do:

```
$first = [1, 2, 3];
$second = ["A", "B"];
$res = [];

array_map(
    function ($num) use (&$res, $second) {
        array_map(
            function ($sym) use (&$res, $num) {
                $res[] = "$num $sym";
            },
            $second
        );
    },
    $first
);
```

And more elegant way but less effective in speed performance, because additionally we use `array_merge`:

```
$first = [1, 2, 3];
$second = ["A", "B"];

$res = array_merge(...array_map(
    fn($num) => array_map(
        fn($sym) => "$num $sym",
        $second
    ),
    $first
));
```